# Story Identification: Novel/Short Story set in space with a mesh-like satellite

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space

I remember reading this at my local library whilst I waited for my brother. I think it was in a book with a few other short stories.

What I can remember:

- Some sort of mesh/net/grid shaped satellite orbiting earth, and it was malfunctioning. I'm pretty sure it was a communication satellite of some form.
- It has two protagonists in their teens. I don't know how or why they were in space, but they were.

  - They fix the satellite against some guy's orders to stay away from it.
  - I think they 'live' in space, i.e. they haven't come for a trip from Earth, they actually live on a space station nearby the mesh (I remember this because they travel to it from wherever they are).
- There were some bad guy(s) causing the malfunction.

It was a pretty worn book, so I'm thinking it was written earlier than the 90s (I read it in 98/99).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like [*The Planetoid Grid* by Nicholas Marrat](http://www.reginaldalecmartin.co.uk/tpg.htm), published in the anthology [*A Book of Boys' Stories* by Robert Bateman and Nicholas Marrat](http://www.reginaldalecmartin.co.uk/bbs.htm), which was not exclusively science fiction.

The boys were "Space born scouts" named Bluey and Tinder.

Two other plot details that I remember:

- One of the boys uses the phrase "go swallow a spheroid" as an insult.
- The satellite used rubies to transmit sound at the speed of light, and was malfunctioning because the bad guys were stealing them.

Comment: Yep, that rings a bell! Thanks :-)